# Can I get UDP Hole Punching with (any) VNC client to get around the local firewall/router?

Tags: firewall, vnc, udp

I don't have access to the local internet router, so I'm unable to setup port forwarding on my lan connection. I'm just trying to find out if there is any way for me to get around my local router firewall. Perhaps there are any VNC clients that support UDP hole punching?

Comment: Questions about bypassing security are generally not received well on SuperUser.

Comment: You will most likely be limited to services like Teamviewer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Features) UltraVNC has a Repeater server for NAT passthrough. Though it should be achievable with any VNC that supports a listen mode and the right UDP Hole Punching tool.